# Why $r$ is a function of $\theta$? (polar coordinate)

Tags: functions, polar-coordinates, classical-mechanics

I am reading "Key Points of Mechanics" by Haruo Yoshida.

He wrote $r$ was a function of $\theta$. (please see below.)

But if $\theta(t_0)=\theta(t_1)$ and $r(t_0) \neq r(t_1)$ for $t_0 \neq t_1$, $r$ is not a function of $\theta$.

Please explain why $r$ is a function of $\theta$.

> The equations of motion in a polar coordinate system are the following:
>
> $m (\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2) = f_r$,
>   $m(r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta})=f_{\theta}$.
>
> If $f_r := -\frac{GMm}{r^2}, f_{\theta}:=0$, then
>   $\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2 = -\frac{GM}{r^2}$,
>   $r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}=0$.
>
> $\frac{d}{dt}(r^2\dot{\theta}) = 2r\dot{r}\dot{\theta}+r^2\ddot{\theta} = r(r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta})=0$.
>
> So, $r^2\dot{\theta}$ is constant.
>   Let $h := r^2\dot{\theta}$.
>
> $\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2 = \ddot{r}-r(\frac{h}{r^2})^2 = \ddot{r}-\frac{h^2}{r^3} = -\frac{GM}{r^2}$.
>
> $r$ is a function of $\theta$ and the following equation holds:
>   $\frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{dr}{d\theta})=\frac{1}{r}-\frac{GM}{h^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're concerned about is that, after rotating through $2\pi$ radians, $r$ can change. The general approach in orbital mechanics is to let $\theta$ change continuously, even though that means it has to eventually go outside $[0,\,2\pi)$. For example, suppose the object spirals exponentially into the origin: then constants $a,\,b$ exist for which $r=a\exp(-b\theta)$ describes the path, provided we see $\theta$ become arbitrarily large over time. (There's a discussion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral) of the case where the object spirals exponentially outward instead.)

It's been pointed out by @YvesDaoust that some other paths repeat old values of $\theta$ even without this looping effect. In this case, we'll have no choice but to take $r$ as a multivalued function of $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you very much, J.G..

Answer (score 1):

This can arise with any parametric equation of a curve. In

$$\begin{cases}x=x(t)=t^2,\\y=y(t)=t\end{cases}$$

it is impossible to express $y$ as a true, univocal function of $x$,

$$y=f(x),$$ as $$y=\pm\sqrt x.$$

You can understand the author's statement as "$r$ is a multifunction of $\theta$", or just loosely "$r$ varies with $\theta$".

Comment: Thank you very much, Yves Daoust.

Comment: @tchappyha: you were wrong to accept the other answer, this has nothing to do with phase ambiguity. Think of a pendulum with slowly varying length: it is such that the angle remains in $[-\pi,\pi]$, but passes by zero infinitely many times with a different radius.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the solution to these equations does have $r$ as a function of $\theta$, but this depends greatly on this particular potential function.

---

Starting with
$$
\ddot{r}-r\dot\theta^2=-\frac{GM}{r^2}\tag1
$$
and
$$
r\ddot\theta+2\dot{r}\dot\theta=0\tag2
$$
equation $(2)$ says that
$$
\dot\theta=\frac{k_1}{r^2}\tag3
$$
Plugging $(3)$ into $(1)$ gives
$$
\ddot{r}=\frac{k_1^2}{r^3}-\frac{GM}{r^2}\tag4
$$
Apply $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{k_1}{r^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{r}
&=\frac{k_1}{r^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\\
&=-k_1\frac{\mathrm{d}\frac1r}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
and again:
$$
\begin{align}
\ddot{r}
&=-\frac{k_1^2}{r^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\frac1r}{\mathrm{d}\theta^2}\\
&=\frac{k_1^2}{r^3}-\frac{GM}{r^2}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\frac1r}{\mathrm{d}\theta^2}
&=\frac{GM}{k_1^2}-\frac1r\tag7
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{GM}{k_1^2}-\frac1r=k_2\cos(\theta-\theta_0)\tag8
$$
Solving for $r$ yields
$$
r=\frac1{\frac{GM}{k_1^2}-k_2\cos(\theta-\theta_0)}\tag9
$$
which is [the polar equation for an ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3463417), but the important part is that $r$ is a function of $\theta$.

[image]